# XAMPP: Apache binds to all IP addresses of host

Tags: apache

I have a XAMPP installation on Windows 2008 R2 that I have to support. The facts are these:

- The computer has 3 IP addresses (25, 59 and 130, each 192.168.43.)
- Apache and IIS need to run side by side (IIS is used for application pools)
- The apache is configured to listen only on IP 25
- Accessing any of the other IP addresses yields a message from the apache

The following configuration files have been adapted to the IP address listen/bind change (from the default installation):

- httpd.conf lists "Listen 192.168.43.25:80"
- httpd.conf lists "ServerName 192.168.43.25:80"
- extra/httpd-ssl.conf lists "Listen 192.168.43.25:443"

I have no explanation for this behaviour. Whenever I access one of the other IP addresses, I get the following lines in the "access.log":

*192.168.43.130 - - [25/Apr/2012:11:41:47 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0"*

*192.168.43.130 - - [25/Apr/2012:11:41:47 +0200] "GET /xampp/ HTTP/1.1" 403 1371 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0"*

I'm not sure what to make of this. I'm pretty sure that this is my fault, that I somehow do not get the configuration, yet it seems straight forward correct.

Please help me. Thank you. I'll try to answer any questions in a matter of minutes.